# I have a customized form but whatever written on the form is not saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]I have a form that uses styles of twitter/bootstrap
however the content of the form is not saved.
May I please know what am I missing?

```
    <%= form_for @customer_detail, url: { action: "create" } do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <label for="Check in">Check in:</label><br>

                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input class="form-control" type='text'>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class=
                            "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div><label for="Check out">Check out:</label><br>

                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                            <input class="form-control" type='text'>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class=
                            "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: your form does not point to a controller action.

Comment: The following link is customer_detail content: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o2hvHLlIlXCMIloXUNF5yL2cVLGTGTOgRotxx5vNvok/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @mark yes I have shared some code, if it is not too much to ask please advise, thank you for your time.

Comment: How does your controller look like that provides the `@customer_detail` variable?

Comment: @ mark controller for customer detail   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o2hvHLlIlXCMIloXUNF5yL2cVLGTGTOgRotxx5vNvok/edit